# What is latest supported version of mono for CentOS 5.2?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, centos5

I need to install Mono on a CentOS 5.2 (Final) system.
Does anybody know what is the latest supported version of mono for this OS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Centos:

```
curl --silent http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/repodata/2334a1db7cede46ffeaca271f392cefb85db58f27b1f4154bce97913f18a7301-filelists.xml.gz | gzip -d -c | grep "mono-basic-"
    <file>./mono-basic-3.8.tar.bz2</file>
    <file>./mono-basic-4.0.tar.bz2</file>
    <file>./mono-basic-4.0.1.tar.bz2</file>
```

So, **4.0.1** is available currently for centOS, you would have to check your dependancies to see what else might need to be updated for your centOS 5.2 install.

Setup :

> CentOS, Fedora, and derivatives Add the Mono Project GPG signing key
>   and the package repository in a root shell with:

```
> rpm --import "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
> yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/
```

> Run a package upgrade to
>   upgrade existing packages to the latest available. Then install Mono
>   as described in the Usage section.
>
> Users of CentOS or RHEL (or similar distributions) may need to add the
>   EPEL repository to their system to satisfy all dependencies.

From : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#centos-fedora-and-derivatives

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am able to verify 4.0.1 can be build/ compiled on my CentOS 5.2 system. As you pointed out some special setup is needed on my system. Thanks.